# Дополнить один DF значениями из второго Python

Tags: python, pandas

Итак, есть исходный DF:

```
FIRM    X1  Mount
1   5   31.12.2005
1   5   31.12.2006
1   6   31.12.2007
1   3   30.11.2010
2   6   28.02.2006
2   2   29.02.2008
2   6   28.02.2009
2   2   29.02.2012
```

И есть второй DF:

```
FIRM    X2  Mount
1   5   31.12.2005
1   3   31.12.2006
1   2   31.12.2007
2   1   28.02.2006
2   4   29.02.2008
2   1   28.02.2009
```

Нужно заполнить первый DF данными из второго, если нет значения, то ставим пропуск, то есть в итоге должно получить вот это:

```
FIRM    X1  Mount   X2
1   5   31.12.2005  5
1   5   31.12.2006  3
1   6   31.12.2007  2
1   3   30.11.2010  -
2   6   28.02.2006  1
2   2   29.02.2008  4
2   6   28.02.2009  1
2   2   29.02.2012  -
```

Comment: __NOTE:__ использование минусов вместо `NaN` - автоматически конвертирует тип столбца `X2` в строку (`object`) - если планируете далее использовать числа из этого столбца, то лучше оставить `NaN`

Comment: Да, лучше Nan оставить!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['FIRM', 'Mount'], how='left').fillna('-')
```

---

```
 FIRM  X1        Mount  X2
0   1   5   31.12.2005  5
1   1   5   31.12.2006  3
2   1   6   31.12.2007  2
3   1   3   30.11.2010  -
4   2   6   28.02.2006  1
5   2   2   29.02.2008  4
6   2   6   28.02.2009  1
7   2   2   29.02.2012  -
```

Comment: А можно оставить пустоты как NaN

Comment: @Max52, просто уберите `.fillna('-')`